# How to make my website load faster built with laravel vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

so I just got hired , and I was giving the task of optimizing a new site they want to launch soon , https://bizguruh.com  , so far I have tried everything I can,reduced image size,   but it doesn't seem to be helping , any ideas from anyone would be greatly appreciated please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just visit your side, You can do one thing in that. I have noticed there are many CSS and JS files used in your site. But many of them in their actual version.

You can minify all CSS and JS file's code with Laravel's [Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix) Feature
 This will convert the whole code in single line so It won't take much load

Comment: Yeah I noticed the size of the app.js file, lemme walk on it now , thanks

Comment: Yeah, I suggest you convert your all custom CSS and JS file in minified version, that will really increase loading time.

Comment: And ya I see your images are in .png format it will better if you convert in .jpeg format

Comment: Quick question please,  how would I have add cdn links into the mix

Comment: well you don't have to add CDN, because CDN are already minified you have to add only custom files.

For an initial test minify custom files and check If still you want better performance then open that CDN file and copy  whole code and paste and save that file and then convert it in minify

Comment: okay, thanks, i added all ,y custom css, and custom js to the mix, now my app.js size is 17mb, how do i minify it, or does it get minified when i run npm run production? sorry if i'm asking so much, im still a bit new to laravel, thanks

Comment: Well not an issue, I also had more question when I was learning,

Btw yeah you have to execute all npm commands afterward it will minify

Comment: them execute npm run watch too

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, i really appreciate

Comment: Please approve this answer / upvote too and welcome sir btw

Answer (score 0):

not all your js and css are minified, for example app.js is really huge, minify it may help a lot.